# jQuery - how to trigger a lightbox when click on table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, fancybox, lightbox

Sample table:

```
<table>

<tr class="record" id="10">
    <td>1/1/2010</td>
    <td>$10.00</td>
</tr>

<tr class="record" id="11">
    <td>1/3/2010</td>
    <td>$15.00</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I am using this JS to grab the `id` from the table row when clicked, and form a URL (some CodeIgniter markup).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr.record').bind('click', function() {
        var record_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var link = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>expenses/edit/' + record_id;
    });
});
```

With that URL, I would like to open a PHP/HTML page in a lightbox.

Most jQuery lightbox solutions (fancybox, jQuery Tools overlay) require the `a href` to trigger.

I wonder if anyone can point me in the direction of how to get this done automatically after the JS above -- that is, once `record_id` is known, form the URL, and then automatically trigger a lightbox which shows my PHP/HTML page inside.

Any pointers on this? Any solutions are welcome, regardless of the jQuery lightbox you prefer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr.record').bind('click', function(){

        var record_id   = $(this).attr("id");
        var link        = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>expenses/edit/' + record_id;

        $.fancybox({
            'width'             : '75%',
            'height'            : '75%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'href'              : link
        });

    });
});
```

For more information about the parameters check:
http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: that's very close to what I wanted, thanks a lot! There's an issue though -- it requires 2 clicks on the row in order to open the box -- is there a way of activating the box with a single click?

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by using `hover` instead of `click` (line 2) -- but if you have a better solution let me know -- thx!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Regarding the double click issue: try $.fancybox instead of $(this).fancybox, that should fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use fancybox which is much better than lightbox and it can be implemented pretty much the same way as lightbox. You can try this with lightbox. Basically all I did to get the table row to act as a link to trigger fancybox was declare the table row as:

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick='parent.$.fancybox({href:"#dom"}); return false;'></tr>
```

You can also do the same for a table cell:

```
<td style="cursor:pointer" onclick='parent.$.fancybox({href:"#dom"}); return false;'></td>
```

For the href, reference the link, div, id, or class you're calling that contains the content you want to display.

If you're using lightbox you can probably write something like this:

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer" onclick='parent.$.lightbox({href:"#dom"}); return false;'></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).

Haven't used it myself, but some of the demos seem to do what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks @jmccarthy - got a good solution above using fancybox (which is already in use in my project)